# Let Z be a standard normal random variable and calculate the following probabilities, indicating the regions under the standard normal curve

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

**Let Z be a standard normal random variable and calculate the following probabilities, indicating the regions under the standard normal curve?**

**a) $P(0 < Z < 2.17)$**

**b) $P(-2.50 < Z < 2.50)$**

So I used the [Normal Distribution Calculator](http://stattrek.com/online-calculator/normal.aspx#TopPage) to obtain:

$P(0 < Z < 2.17) = 0.98500 - 0.50000 = 0.485$

Similarly I got for b):

$P(-2.50 < Z < 2.50) = 0.99379 - 0.00621 = 0.98758$

I'm really not sure how to "*indicate the region though*"

I tried looking at this table [Standard Normal Distribution Table](http://college.cengage.com/mathematics/brase/understanding_basic/3e/students/appendix/app_andm.pdf)

Yet I am not really sure how to use it..Looking at the table would that mean that the region my answer $0.485$ would be in is $8$%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first plot should look like this:

[image]

Now can you draw the second one?

Answer (score 0):

You are expected to find or make a curve like you find by searching "standard normal distribution".  Your $Z$ is the horizontal coordinate.  Then color in the range of $Z$ called out in each part of the question.

Comment: heropup has it exactly right.